# Django relationships to inherited model from parent model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 4 models in django, here are 3 of them (the 4th one is the default user model):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    content = TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class NewsArticle(Post):
    link = URLField(default='')
    external_id = CharField(unique=True,
                            max_length=50, help_text='The ID of the news article from the source')
    source = CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Name of source website')

class Like(models.Model):
    LIKE_CHOICES = [('L', 'Like'), ('D', 'Dislike')]

    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
    state = CharField(default='L', max_length=1, choices=LIKE_CHOICES)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_state_display()
```

According to my understanding, this way the news articles aren't linked to likes at all. My goal is to get all news articles and `select_related()` the likes on them. I don't want to create a new model just for news article likes also. What can I do here?

Comment: Are you trying to use your Post class as a 'base' model for other classes or it is an actual meaningful class?

Comment: I'm using it as a base

Comment: Ok give me 5 minutes I'm writing the answer

Comment: Great - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Content type is the answer!** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Since your Post class is just a base for other models your should mark it as abstract so Django will not create a table for it in the DB first of all:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  title = CharField(max_length=200)
  content = TextField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

In your NewsArticle class:

```
class NewsArticle(Post):
  link = URLField(default='')
  external_id = CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, help_text='The ID of the news article from the source')
  source = CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Name of source website')
  likes = GenericRelation(Like)
```

In your Like class:

```
class Like(models.Model):
  LIKE_CHOICES = [('L', 'Like'), ('D', 'Dislike')]

  user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  state = CharField(default='L', max_length=1, choices=LIKE_CHOICES)
  created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.get_state_display()
```

Comment: Can you explain this is doing? Also shouldn't like be on the post model?

Comment: Please take a look here, it takes long to explain but easy to understand https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: How can I get all news articles with their corresponding like?

Comment: @ninesalt example query for the first news article in queryset:    NewsArticle.objects.all().first().likes

Comment: @ninesalt Another example is:    article = NewsArticle.objects.all().first()           Like.objects.filter(content_object=article)